# How to change spacing between caption numbering and text?

Tags: spacing, captions

Like in an IEEE paper, after the figure caption numbering, there are two letters spacing:

```
Fig. 1.  Bla bla
```

Not like

```
Fig. 1. Bla bla
```

I would like to have the former.

Answer (score 6):

With `caption` package, this is how it can be done.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mylabel}{#1 #2.\hspace{1.5ex}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=mylabel,labelsep=none,name=Fig.}
```

Change `1.5ex` to whatever you want.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mylabel}{#1 #2.\hspace{1.5ex}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=mylabel,labelsep=none,name=Fig.}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is my figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change

Comment: this gives an end-of-sentence space after 'Fig.", which isn't great.  since whatever fills in `#1` will probably be short, a `~` could safely be put between `#1~#2` to make this even more distinct from the space following the figure number.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this may only be an optical illusion, as [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) inserts a single `\nobreakspace` (or tie `~`) between both the caption label/number and the number/title. However, if you want to mimic (or adjust) caption-related content, it's best to use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption).

The `caption` package provides the key `labelsep` that defines your separation between the caption label and title. For illustration, below are some of the default options, together with some ones created:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{qquad}{\qquad}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{bigspace}{.\hspace*{4em}}
\begin{document}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\captionsetup{labelsep=quad}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\captionsetup{labelsep=qquad}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\captionsetup{labelsep=bigspace}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\end{document}
```